# Blur operation in fragment shader with floating point values

Tags: floating-point, glsl, fragment-shader, framebuffer, depth-buffer

I'm trying to perform blur operation in fragment shader by attaching a texture(myTexture) to my framebuffer object. It works with this code:

```
vec3 blur(float depth){
float dx = 1.0f/800;
float dy = 1.0f/800;
vec3 sum = vec3(0,0,0);
int dep=depth*10;
for(int i=-dep;i<dep;i++) 
for(int j=-dep;j<dep;j++) 
    sum += texture(myTexture, otex + vec2(i * dx, j  * dy)).xyz;
return sum/40;
}
```

But if I alter it to the below code, it doesnt work(The screen goes white for some reason, may be its reading from my depth texture but I don't know why)

```
vec3 blur(float depth){
float dx = 1.0f/800;
float dy = 1.0f/800;
vec3 sum = vec3(0,0,0);
float dep=depth*10;
for(float i=dep;i<dep;i+=0.2f) 
for(float j=dep;j<dep;j+=0.2f) 
    sum += texture(myTexture, otex + vec2(i * dx, j  * dy)).xyz;
return sum/40;
}
```

The reason I'm trying to do this because I want to blur according to the depth value of the object. If the object is far, blur more. If it is near, blur less.
If I use the first code, I get a stepped blur, i.e, if depth is 0.3 blur thrice, if depth is 0.2 blur twice.......
I want to use the floating point values so that I get a smooth transition between blur values instead of stepped values

What am I doing wrong? Also, is there any other way to get a smooth transition between blur values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you got 2 problems:

1. **normalize with `sum/40`**

   instead of constant `40` you should divide by the number of additions which is `~(2*10*depth)^2` in the first code. The second code is wrong ...
2. **wrong loop in second code**

   The resulting `sum` of your second chunk is `(0,0,0)` so it should be black unless you are doing something on top of this. Because you got error in:

   ```
   for(float i=dep;i<dep;i+=0.2f) 
   for(float j=dep;j<dep;j+=0.2f)
   ```

   it is never going inside. I assume you wanted this instead:

   ```
   for(float i=-dep;i<dep;i+=0.2f) 
   for(float j=-dep;j<dep;j+=0.2f)
   ```

   in such case you should normalize with `~(2*10*5*depth)^2`